# Browserify fails

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browserify

Hellow I'm starting a new angular and CoffeScript project and I've decided to use browserify but failed before even started I'm getting an error that angular.module is not a function :

```
angular = require "./angular"
angular.module "app", []
angular.bootstrap document.body, ["app"]

Uncaught TypeError: angular.module is not a function
```

Index.html contains only a single  so I'll omit it.

I found that if I enter angular.module("app", []) in console manually afther the page has loaded everything is Ok ...

Comment: single script with src="./bundle.js"* I'm bundeling with `browserify app.js -o bundle.js`

Comment: I have no other deps except angular and I have it in the folder where app.js and index.html are ...

Comment: `angular = require "./angular"
console.log angular
angular.module "app", []
angular.bootstrap document.body, ["app"]` This logs "{}"

Answer (score 0):

Runing `npm install angular` in the the project folder and using `angular = require "angular"` fixed the error

Comment: That will apply to any module you wanto to use. You need to install it locally or globally and then require where you need it.